# XSLT transformation datetime to date format

Tags: .net, xslt, xsd

I'm trying to transform a datetime to a date format yyyy-MM-dd, because I'm using the xsd.exe tool the xs:date datatypes are automatically changed into a datetime datatype, because there is no type in the .NET Framework that matches the type xs:date completely.

But I can't get it to work

```
<articles>
        <article>
          <articleid>48992</articleid>
          <deliverydateasked>2009-01-29T00:00:00+01:00</deliverydateasked>
        </article>
        <article>
          <articleid>48993</articleid>
          <deliverydateasked>2009-01-30T00:00:00+01:00</deliverydateasked>
        </article>
</articles>
```

trying to convert the xml to

```
<articles>
        <article>
          <articleid>48992</articleid>
          <deliverydateasked>2009-01-29</deliverydateasked>
        </article>
        <article>
          <articleid>48993</articleid>
          <deliverydateasked>2009-01-30</deliverydateasked>
        </article>
</articles>
```

currently I'm using this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <articles>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="article">
        </xsl:apply-templates>
            </articles>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="FormatDate">

    <xsl:param name="DateTime" />
    <xsl:variable name="date">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($DateTime,'T')" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:if test="string-length($date) != 10">
        <xsl:value-of select="$DateTime"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="string-length($date) = 10">
        <xsl:value-of select="$date"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="article">
        <xsl:call-template name="FormatDate">
            <xsl:with-param name="DateTime" select="deliverydateasked"/>
        </xsl:call-template>    
</xsl:template>
```

Does anyone know a good xslt transformation.

Thanks in advance

The output result of my code is

```
<articles />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Stesoc and annakata I figured it out
This is the code I'm now using and it works perfect

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:param name="parentElm">
        <xsl:value-of select="name(..)" />
    </xsl:param>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'deliverydateasked'">
            <xsl:element name="deliverydateasked">
                <xsl:call-template name="FormatDate">
                    <xsl:with-param name="DateTime" select="."/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="FormatDate">
    <xsl:param name="DateTime" />
    <xsl:variable name="date">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($DateTime,'T')" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:if test="string-length($date) != 10">
        <xsl:value-of select="$DateTime"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="string-length($date) = 10">
        <xsl:value-of select="$date"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Why do you do the complicated "local-name()" stuff?

Comment: what tomalak said - leverage xsl:copy

Comment: Annakata I have tried your first suggestion <xsl:template match="*"> <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates /></xsl:copy></xsl:template> with result: <articles>2009-01-292009-01-30</articles> Or did I something wrong? but is local-name() than a function to avoid? the duration time is now 15-30 ms

Answer (score 8):

Formatting will get a lot easier in XPath 2.0, which Microsoft has currently refused to support for the last 8 years.  Since the formatting issue is really only persistent for XSLT in .Net I like to use a custom function, which is cleaner & easier:

XSLT With Formatting Function:

```
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:user="http://www.tempuri.org/User">

  <msxsl:script implements-prefix="user" language="C#">
        <![CDATA[
          public string FormatCurrency(string amount)
          {
            return decimal.Parse(amount).ToString("C0");
          }

          public string FormatDate(string dateValue)
          {
            return DateTime.Parse(dateValue).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
          }
          ]]>
      </msxsl:script>
```

Usage:

```
<xsl:value-of select="user:FormatDate(@transactionDate)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="user:FormatCurrency(@amount)"/>
```

When you execute your XSLT in .Net make sure to tell it that it's trusted (so that the msxsl:script block will run.

```
XslCompiledTransform.Load(reader, XsltSettings.TrustedXslt, null);
```

Answer (score 7):

Frankly, this looks about right to me - sometimes a simple substring is good enough.

However, if you're in .NET land and you're really needing extra functionality .NET has [XSLT Extension Objects](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/031112.htm)

---

edit: oic, you've got a basic apply-templates conceptual problem. Try this (note the copy and the root template match):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates /></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="deliverydateasked">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:call-template name="FormatDate">
            <xsl:with-param name="DateTime" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>    
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="FormatDate">

        <xsl:param name="DateTime" />
        <xsl:variable name="date">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($DateTime,'T')" />
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:if test="string-length($date) != 10">
                <xsl:value-of select="$DateTime"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="string-length($date) = 10">
                <xsl:value-of select="$date"/>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

templates is a hard concept to learn, you might be better off starting with the more straightforward `for-each`, and/or it seems you could do with some XSLT tutorials/books.

Comment: On "using the more straightforward for-each": http://gregbeech.com/blogs/tech/archive/2006/08/17/using-xsl-for-each-is-almost-always-wrong.aspx. I vote for doing it properly from the start. :)

Comment: From personal experience of teaching XSLT to newbies I strongly disagree with that - for-each is a translatable and easily grasped concept, and if anything is a handy springboard to explain the template concept "now you've got that, see what this can do!"

Comment: The link Tomalak gave to the Greg Beech article has changed; it's now http://gregbeech.com/blog/using-xsl-for-each-is-almost-always-wrong