# Formatting DateTime in XSLT

Tags: xslt

How can I change below two fields, format of dateTime in XSLT.

DateTime format

```
<startdate>2002-05-30T09:30:10+06:00</startdate>

<MidDate>2002-05-30T09:30:10+06:00</MidDate>
```

I needed as:

```
<startdate>2002-05-30 09:30:10</startdate>

<MidDate>2002-05-30 9:30</MidDate>
```

Comment: What have you looked into/tried? What version of XSLT?

Comment: Are you facing any problem, because it is simple string manipulation in XSL 1.0. Second thing, if you have done anything from your side, share it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSLT transformation datetime to date format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487779/xslt-transformation-datetime-to-date-format)

Comment: my XSLT is 1.0. When coming from input, schema validation happens and it is accepting only when it is complete DateTime format i.e., having T in middle and appending at end. But my detination wants in the other formats i mentioned. I am practicing XSL now.

Comment: Do you omit inthe leading zeros in the datetime components. Especially in ISO 8601 datetimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within XSLT 1.0 you can use `substring()` as follows:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring('2002-05-30T09:30:10+06:00', 1, 10)" /><xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="substring('2002-05-30T09:30:10+06:00', 12, 8)" />
```

Above will output:
**2002-05-30 09:30:10**

If you don't want the seconds attached, you simply adjust the substring a little:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring('2002-05-30T09:30:10+06:00', 1, 10)" /><xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="substring('2002-05-30T09:30:10+06:00', 12, 5)" />
```

Which will output:
**2002-05-30 9:30**

---

If you are able to use XSLT 2.0, you can use `format-date()` as described in the standard documentation: [Formatting Date and Times](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#format-date)

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-date('2002-05-30T09:30:10+06:00', '[Y01]-[M01]-[D01] [H]:[m]:[s]')" />
```